# Cyclone DDS Supported in Dashing?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a bit confused if cyclone dds is supported in dashing...
Installed it like described [here.](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Working-with-Eclipse-CycloneDDS/)

The demo talker / listener is working, so it should be in the list of supported rmw implementations.
But when I want to build my workspace and do `--cmake-force-configure` or even clean my workspace and rebuild, I always get:

`The RMW implementation has been specified as 'rmw_cyclonedds_cpp' through the environment variable 'RMW_IMPLEMENTATION', however it is not in the list of supported rmw implementations, which was specified when the 'rmw_implementation' package was built.`

And I think the message is wrong, because the installed `demo_nodes_cpp talker/listener` is working, so it has to have support!?

My system:
ROS Dashing, Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336389/cyclone-dds-supported-in-dashing?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2019-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation/pull/68 has been merged and released into Dashing the problem should go away.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2